# Multiple streams reading from the same file

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have a number of input files, which I'm reading in parallel and performing computations on every line that I read. However, for every line (in every file), I need to access one of about hundred files, loop through the entirety it and write the every combination into an output file.

So, basically, I have something like this (*note, that I only added the crucial parts of the code*):

```
int numberOfFiles = (int) new File("path/").listFiles().length;

IntStream.range(0, numberOfFiles).parallel().forEach(k -> { 
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("priorityQueuePreTerminal"+k+".txt")));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("priorityQueuePostTerminal"+k+".txt"), true));
        ...
        try {
            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ){ 
            ...
                BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("shared/"+i+".txt")));
                while( (line2 = br2.readLine()) != null ){ 
                    bw.write(...);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { } finally { br2.close(); }
    } catch (Exception e) { } finally { br.close(); bw.close(); }
});
```

What essentially happens, is that two input files can read from the same one of those hundred shared files, at the same time. 
The end result is, that one of the output files is always fully completed, like it should be, while all the other output files have the starting few lines, and then they end prematurely.

Am I even able to read from the same shared file by multiple streams (I was under the impression that reading from the same file by multiple resources was fine, but writing could be problematic)? Is there an equivalent to `synchronized` in Java 8 streams, to make sure that one stream is currently reading only from one file?

Comment: If you're using Java 8, do yourself a favour by using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to close your streams correctly.

Comment: this is not `java8 stream` , the code is between `java7 and java8` as the use of `{}` for more then one line is discouraged.

Comment: are you trying to read from one file and writing to another?

Comment: Yes, I'm *not* reading and writing into same files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello reading in parallel a file is a really bad idea. Because your hardware your hard drive is constrained by some number. Lets say 700 MB per second. At one point no matter how much more you read in paralel eventually you will not see any performance gains. Try to optimize your data processing in parallel instead of you IO access to the disk.

Although not a real answer. My advice to you is to read all the files at ones into the memory or as much as you can into the memory. And then do the multithreading in the processing part of the assignment instead one the file reading.

Comment: I'm sending this onto a grid, so hardware really isn't a problem.

Comment: Are you saying that the files are located into a grid ? Or do you mean that after you read them in parallel you are uploading the content t a grid.

Comment: I'm sending the executable .jar, as well as all of the necessary input files and shared files that need to be read from, onto the grid. So, yes, they are all located on it. Once the output files are created, I fetch them from the grid.

Comment: But aren't you reading the files from the disk initially? The reading is what is constraining you.

Comment: The problem is, that I'm not sure if I can read all of the shared files into the memory, because there's a lot of them and they're big (and I'm already using quite a lot of memory with the computations, anyway). That's why I was going to read from them during the operation, to prevent any memory-related issues. The processing isn't the hardest part here. It's  the fact, that I have a lot of input files. That's why I was parallelizing on the files in the first place.

Comment: It is not about reading all of them. Read a big chunk do processing of this chunk. Read next big chunk do processing and so on. But dont use multiple threads when reading the big chunk. Use multiple threads when processing it.

Comment: Even better it is if you read in this one thread while processing in the other many threads for best performance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116673/discussion-between-noelaramis-and-alexander-petrov).